# Best way to make a background image link to an external URL

Tags: css, background-image

I have an image slider that displays images using:

```
style=background:url(images/main/_slider/Homepage/20-alt.jpg)
```

You can see the full page here: http://www.robertfitzroyacademy.com/index-test.html.

I am trying to get the first slide to link to an external URL but cannot work out how to do this. I know that I cannot get a background:url to link directly to the external URL, but I cannot get  tags to work nor found a way to set a clickable "block/button" within  tags.

Not sure if this is possible or if, I am just looking at this the wrong way. Either way any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks,

Hanniel

Comment: Are you trying to link to the image or just another external page like www.example.com? Also, please post the minimal code here and not a link to your site. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="your_external_page_link" style="display: block;"><div style="background: url('your_img_url'); height: 200px; width: 200px;"></div></a>.
```

You can try the above code if it works. You will have to specify height and width externally.

Comment: Hi, this method seems to be almost there. Many thanks!!! However, the div box blocks the background image completely, is there a way to make it hidden/transparent?

Comment: For your reference you can see your code in action here: http://www.robertfitzroyacademy.com/index-test.html

Comment: Give the width from 200px to 100% and height to 1000px from 600px

Comment: Hi Shaili, sorry for delayed reply. In the end, I used a modal as a fix, as I was up against a deadline. However, this solution is so close to perfect I REALLY wanted to see if we could get this fully answered. I did as instructed and the link now works with the slide image showing. However, the background image has now altered (it has been made bigger). I have uploaded to the link given previously above, using the same image for the first two slides so that you can see the difference. Both slides use the same size image, the first slide has the external link.

Comment: Hi Hanniel, Can you please vote for my answer if it helped you?

Comment: Hi Shaili, can you tell me how to fix the increased image size that your solution has caused?

Answer (score 0):

You should add anchor tag just after list tag and also need to add css  like following:

```
<li style="background:url(images/main/_slider/Homepage/20-alt.jpg) no-repeat bottom center" class="slide-item">
  <a href="#">
  <div class="flex-caption-wrapper" onclick='window.location.href="https://www.schoolinterviews.co.uk/code?z=uXf1aA"'>
    <!--div class="flex-caption">
    <p>Welcome to Robert Fitzroy Academy</p>
    </div-->
  </div>
  <a>
</li>
```

**Your css like this:**

```
.slide-item a {
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this 
The best way to try a background image is this .
This way I can have a background image in slider and this image is showing up .

The question was image as background is not  showing up .
I asked him to try this inline css.
I am trying to get the first slide to link to an external URL but cannot work out how to do this. I know that I cannot get a background:url to link directly to the external URL, but I cannot get tags to work nor found a way to set a clickable "block/button" within tags.

```
background-image:url(https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/a/1350072692/t1/img/front_page/jp-mountain@2x.jpg);
```

Comment: @disinfor  This is the way to add external url as background and this image is working.

Comment: The OP isn't trying to add an external image as a background image. They want to be able to click the first slide's background image to go to an external URL.